# Can a Monk with Lycanthropy use Flurry of Blows in Animal form?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, monk, character-templates, lycanthropy

I am about to begin playing a Pathfinder game in which I am playing an unchained monk. My character has the natural lycanthrope template applied and his animal form is that of a dire wolf.

Can I still use my flurry of blows while in **animal form**?

Per the RAW for the [lycanthropy template](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/monster-listings/templates/lycanthrope/):

> **Special Attacks:** A lycanthrope retains all the special attacks, qualities, and abilities of the base creature. In hybrid or animal form it gains the special attacks, qualities, and abilities of the base animal.

I know I can use my flurry of blows in hybrid form. If I'm not mistaken though, I should be able to use the flurry of blows in dire wolf form, right?

Answer (score 3):

#### Yes

Every creature has an unarmed strike, and you retain your abilities in animal form. You can make a flurry of blows (but do note that your bite attack is *not* usable with a flurry unless you take [Feral Combat Training)](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/combat-feats/feral-combat-training-combat/).